# Rails different sql between scope and explicit join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models with these associations:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

And following methods:

```
#In Membership
scope :available_for, -> (user) { joins(:event).merge(Event.available_for(user)) }

#In Event
def self.available_for(user)
  ...
  joins(:memberships).where('memberships.user_id': user.id).ids
  ...
end
```

So in controller when I call:

```
@memberships = @user.memberships.available_for(current_user)
```

Apparently is not the same as:

```
@memberships = @user.memberships.joins(:event).merge(Event.available_for(current_user))
```

In first case it works not as expected, it adds extra AND while join in sql:

```
SELECT "events".id FROM "events" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "events"."id" = "memberships"."event_id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 AND "memberships"."user_id" = $2
```

In second it has no AND:

```
SELECT "events"."id" FROM "events" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "memberships"."event_id" = "events"."id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1
```

I can't get why this is happening, any guess?

Moreover if I change this:

```
@memberships = @user.memberships.available_for(current_user)
```

To this:

```
@memberships = Membership.available_for(current_user).where(user_id: 1)
```

It will work as expected as I added join explicitly as above

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in that "class methods" do not returns active relation. In your sample self.available_for(user) runs method ids and it runs pluck method that do request to DB and returns array of ids.

Comment: It return actually, I return events by particular ids in that class method